# Interceptor not getting invoked on method level

Tags: java, ejb, interceptor

I have a method interceptor. The interceptor is in a separate class, it has also been defined in beans.xml file and have used it at method level. But it is not getting invoked. My code is as follows:

Interceptor class:

```
public class HttpPostInterceptorTest {

@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    Object result = null;
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    if(httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals("GET")){
        //Business Logic
    }else{
        result = context.proceed();
    }

    return result;
}
```

At method level:

```
@Interceptors(HttpPostInterceptorTest.class)
@Transactional
public String save() {
    //Business Logic
    return null;
}
```

Comment: could you show code of  method call? Because Interceptors will only be invoked when the CDI bean method is called using its proxy. So you should call method via injected bean.

Comment: Don't know what `business logic` means in your interceptors, but keep in mind that if you return `null` and not `context.proceed()` the chain of interceptors is broken and the EJB will not get invoked, and the client invoking the `save()` method will get `null`.

Comment: I have read your question better, but I suppose it belongs more to JSF realm rather than EJB. Am I wrong ?